# Is there a way how to add title to Gtk.TextTag?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade

I'm developing Gtk based application with GtkTextView.
I created a GtkTextBuffer and set few tags there.
Here's my code

```
def tag(self, line, msg, bc_color="red"):

    start = self.buff.get_iter_at_line(line)
    end = self.buff.get_iter_at_line(line)
    end.forward_line()

    tag = Gtk.TextTag()
    tag.set_property("background", "red")

    self.buff.get_tag_table().add(tag)
    self.buff.apply_tag(tag, start, end)
```

this method is created in loop in order to set few tags to my text
it looks like this

[image: GtkTextTag]

What I want is to add some pop-up title there, similar to what you get if you set title attribute in HTML. It can be configured to show on mouse hover.

Can you please recommend me something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine [text tags](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTag.html) with a [tooltip](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Tooltip.html). See [this tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.2/sec-tooltips.html.en) for an example which I believe does just what you want.

Comment: problem is that GtkTextTag is ancestor of GObject, but Tooltip can be set just on ancestor of GtkWidget

Comment: @Jan: The linked-to tutorial really does what I think you want, it manually checks the mouse-over position to see if it's in a text tag, and then activates a tool tip. It uses the `query_tooltip` signal, which seems to be undocumented though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tooltips](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktooltips.html) or [Tooltip](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktooltip.html)(if using Gtk 2.12+).